# I cannot upload my iOS project to github

Tags: github

Whenever I  try to upload the project to github the following error is coming.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Please somebody help me. I am new to  to github. I cannot understand what is wrong

Comment: what operating system do you use?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you haven't properly set up your SSH key for github. The GitHub Documentation should be a good place to start help you properly set up your SSH keys.

Comment: This is basically a link only answer, it would be better to copy the jist of the linked article into the answer

Comment: I would definitely take some time and go through github's documentation first to learn about it. Its pretty straight forward and was a hugh resource for me when I first started using it.

Comment: Yes, but link only answers quickly become useless when the link breaks and are considered bad practice on Stack Overflow

Comment: @hardillb I hear you, its not just one article on setting up the SSH.. didnt know how to incorporate each one into my answer.

Comment: @hardillb ok. Gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely trying to connect to GitHub using SSH. Try [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) if you want to use ssh. Instead the more preferred method is to push/pull over HTTPS. Try this instead `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/User/UserRepo.git`. Then if you push, git will ask for your email and password and most probably be successful. Using Https also solves the problem of push/pull behind firewalls

Comment: Thank you for your ans. But i got this message when i try that method.fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/User/UserRepo.git/': Could not resolve proxy: proxyaddress

Comment: You need to replace `User` and `UserRepo.git` with the values appropriate to the repo you are trying to access

Comment: @RawshanMir have you made a empty repository on GitHub first ?

Comment: yeah so place the url of your repo in place of `https://github.com/User/UserRepo.git`